# Copy file to desktop on install

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce to publish a C# application.
Users want a configuration file located on the Desktop.
Can I get the install/update procedure to copy a file to the users desktop? If so, how?

Comment: No way from ClickOnce point of view, but you can check if it exist at your application startup

Comment: I suspected as much. Thank you.